# The nodemon is not being recognized by the terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, package.json, mern, nodemon

I'm following this youtube tutorial on MERN.

Video link:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xKs2IZZya7c&ab_channel=CodingWithDawid

Application github link:

https://github.com/dejwid/mern-blog

At minute 45:00 of the video, he mentions installing nodemon without
go into too much detail. I installed this but nodemon is not working. When I type at the command prompt:

```
nodemon index.js
```

There, an error message appears:

> nodemon : The term 'nodemon' is not recognized as the name of a
> cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
> of the name or, if a path was included, verify that the path is
> correct and try again.
> On line:1 character:1
> + nodemon index.js
> + ~~~~~~~
> + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (nodemon:String) [], CommandNotFoundEx
> conception
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

nodemon is installed globally, as you can see in my package.json

package.json:

```
{
   "dependencies": {
     "express": "^4.18.2",
     "g": "^2.0.1",
     "react-router-dom": "^6.10.0"
   },
   "devDependencies": {
     "nodemon": "^2.0.22"
   }
}
```

Comment: try `npx nodemon index.js`

Comment: Thank you, It works! Congratulations!

Answer (score 1):

the solution is to run as:

```
npx nodemon index.js
```

or to install nodemon globally so it's available as a cli command:

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

ref: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon & https://nodemon.io/

Answer (score 0):

You can add a command in the `scripts` object as key-name `start` in the package.json like below and you can run your application using `npm start`.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index.js",
  }
```

Comment: if `nodemon` is not installed globally, adding it to a script (and calling it as global executable) will fail

Answer (score 0):

There are **2 issues**:-

1. **You have NOT installed nodemon globally**. Brother you are saying that nodemon is installed globally and then you are saying that it is in package.json file. *Please note* :- Globally installed nodemon is not found in the `package.json` file.
2. **You have installed a local version of nodemon**. If you see `nodemon` in your `package.json file`, it means you have installed it *locally*. For locally installed nodemon, writing `nodemon index.js` directly in the terminal does NOT work.

**The solutions** are the following:-

1. To install nodemon globally, you run `npm install --global nodemon` and to verify installation you see it in the list of globally installed modules by running `npm list --global`. Now you can directly run `nodemon index.js` in the terminal command prompt.
2. To install nodemon locally, you run `npm install nodemon` OR `npm install -D nodemon`. Now you cannot directly run nodemon in the terminal. You need to create a script in the package.json using nodemon for example `"[script name]": "nodemon index.js"`. Now in the terminal, you will run `npm run [script name]` to run nodemon.